# Subdomain forward to another subdomain without redirecting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've spent an amout of time to try solve it, and finally without any effects.

I have a casual subdomain like `test.example.com` and a mobile subdomain `m.test.example.com`.  Every subdomain has own directory `test` (I have my scripts here) and `m.test`.
I need to forward users from `m.test.example.com` to `test.example.com` without redirecting to `test.example.com`.

I know it easy to do it by Virtual Hosts or cpanel, but I need to do it on shared hosting with DirectAdmin (user level only). I think about mod_rewrite, and I also tried PHP `symlink()`, but it is disabled on my hosting.

How can I forward the user from the mobile subdomain to non-mobile resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the two domains ("test" and "m.test") have different document roots, you're going to need to reverse proxy. The problem here is mod_proxy, the proxy module, may not be loaded by your host, but you'd do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.test\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.example.com/$1 [L,P]
```

These rules would be in the `/m.test/` folder, the document root of the `m.test.example.com` subdomain. The `P` flag tells mod_rewrite to hand the request to mod_proxy to reverse proxy instead of redirecting the browser.

Comment: it works, but I have an issue that the `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` always returns `test.example.com`.

Comment: @daroPL That's because it's being reverse proxied. There's no other way to do it through the htaccess file if the two subdomains have different document roots.